# amazon s3 bucket image access denide

Tags: android, kotlin

i am try to access uploaded images URL all time but image link expire after some time and show error  " AccessDenied "

i have also make bucket policy public

{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",`enter code here`
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::projectname/foldername/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Did you  give access to your bucket as public read/write?

Comment: yes i have give public bucket policy to read and write @Sajith  https://docs.google.com/document/d/18wXfd82PeLp2tf8i02eXJQmJNruE3iZCR8pcpB_8iF4/edit?usp=sharing please see this doc

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/ this may be help

Comment: can you see this doc? https://docs.google.com/document/d/18wXfd82PeLp2tf8i02eXJQmJNruE3iZCR8pcpB_8iF4/edit?usp=sharing i have use this way to upload and download file,i want to know this way is proper or not?

Comment: Just give a try for my answer . You dont have add `CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead` in your code.

Comment: i'm unable to use CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead because when use this image not upload to S3 bucket! any issue in my bucket policy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193618/discussion-between-full-error-and-sajith).

Answer (score 0):

Write `TransferObserver` like below,

This is `java` code (not `kotlin`)

```
  TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                        transferUtility.upload(yourBucketName, key, file, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```

Comment: when i use CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead raise an error                     <Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>yagneshtest/1558331715454</Key>
<RequestId>B7B44D3EBDC70AD0</RequestId>
<HostId>
5fIvgsGx2BwFaeK0PNN2up5PDW2KU8rrp4N8eebad113EeKR0SAp5r0srq4rAyXKlTrgZNBOD9w=
</HostId>
</Error>  then remove this and run get image access but after 10 to 15 minutes show error access denied!

Comment: did you replace `key` with `unixTime.toString()` like in you code

Comment: yes  i also check to change unixTime.toString() to static key name in both upload time and download time key name like "key" and "test" but still getting NoSuchKey!

Comment: when remove CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead then work fine! but after some time show access denied error! problem in my bucket policy ? or any other step to do for use "CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead"?